# Eventdelegation ignoring target javascript

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have this code

```
<div id='abc' class="formSection" style="margin\: 0 auto;display\: block;max-width\: 1000px;">
    <fieldset>
        <select id="fileList" onchange="refreshPdf(this);"></select>
        <button onclick="disableDiv()">Disable div</button>
        <button onclick="enableDiv()">Enable div</button>
        <div class="cb"></div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<script>
function disableDiv() {
        document.getElementById('abc').hidden = true;
        }
</script>
```

And every time I click disable I get a "[Eventdelegation] ignoring target" back in the code. What can I do/change to make this work?

Comment: Seems to work when I test it. Maybe there's something else in the page / code that is blocking the event?

Comment: I've never seen such a warning(?) Are you using a framework or a library? Or does this message actually appear in your code editor? Anyway, the example code doesn't use event delegation, the message comes from some other code.

Comment: Okay thank you there is so much code I don't know. I have found like this
("#step2 :input").prop("disabled", true); 

but it just disables me the input like button do you know how to disable everything or the <select> element? This would also solve the problem and is not getting me errors.